# The keyboard in my iOS app is too tall on the iPhone 6. How can I adjust the resolution of the keyboard in XCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, ios8, resolution

Currently I am adjusting my already existing iOS App to iOS 8 and the iPhone 6. Currently the keyboard on the iPhone 6 seems pretty tall (like the WhatsApp app before the iPhone 6 Support Update). Can somebody tell me what I have to do, to fix this in my code?

Comment: Have you made your app compatible for the iPhone 6 yet? i.e. is it not zoomed in any more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a coding issue.  Your app is being rendered for the smaller screen sizes and then scaled up to fit the new larger screens (including the keyboard).  You need to include launch images in the native resolutions for the iPhone 6 and 6 plus if you want it to render properly, but you will likely need to be using auto-layout if you want everything to grow to fit the new screen sizes and take advantage of the extra space.

**For iPhone 6:**

750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

**For iPhone 6 Plus:**

1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

or you can go through this link it may help you

http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/

Comment: @wottle what do you mean by "screenshots"?  "launchScreens"?

Comment: Yes, I meant Launch the images. What used to be specified by Default.png. Now I would recommend using the images.xcassets.