# iOS keyboard appears too large. Is this an issue with launch images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, keyboard

In our iOS apps, I have seen that if we leave out certain launch images sizes, that the screen appears as if it is scaled up from a lower resolution device.

When this happens, the devices also display a taller keyboard with chunkier looking text.

When built in on my iPhone 6s+, from Xcode 7.x the keyboard in our app is 1 & 7/8ths" of an inch tall.

Looking at Skype, Slack, Waze, Messages, on the same device the keyboard is 1 & 3/8ths" tall.

I'm using whatever the standard keyboard is when our app's text fields are tapped on.

I have seen that this can be caused by missing launch images at the target device's size, but I'm not sold that this is the only cause.  Does anyone have any insight why an app would appear at a lower resolution than what is native to the device?

Is there a known issue related to launchImages or some other factor that might be causing this?

In some of my testing, at one point I got the app to launch as expected at the correct size after switching full size retina launch images.  This may have been fixed by building under Xcode 8.x, but I'm not sure and we can't do that yet because of other limitations.

Thanks much.

Comment: It appears I was right.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239551/the-keyboard-in-my-ios-app-is-too-tall-on-the-iphone-6-how-can-i-adjust-the-res

Comment: It is easier you avoid launchimages, and create a LaunchScreen.xib instead. Go to "General" tab for your app target, and scroll to "App icons and Launch Images" , where you add the Launch Screen File there and iOS will handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to `Launch Images` in assets because when iPhone 5 came out first, XCode had this functionality to add certain launch image sizes to zoom in the UI of smaller screens and make it compatible to iPhone 5's screen. This was called Branding when I worked on it to make app compatible to bigger screen in a short time.

But it isn't the preferred way and you should avoid using Launch Images, use `Launch.xib` instead to create your Launch Screen. You can also use `Launch.storyboard`, whatever you prefer. It won't zoom in the Keyboard or other UI aspects then.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you.  There are so many details to this, and especially differences when we go between Xcode 7 and 8.  Guess what?  The Retina screens take different sized retina graphics AND the ones from Xcode 8 end up displaying the WRONG keyboard.